# Significato di "cajazza"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Trovò Vita seduta sulle scale, col gatto in grembo. La porta di casa spalancata, **cajazze** isteriche accroccate sui pianerottoli, sulle scale scivolose, nel cortile. I bordanti mangiavano pane e sugo, delusi che tutta questa confusione avesse guastato il loro pranzo di Pasqua.

Sapreste spiegare cosa sono queste "cajazze" che appaiono nel testo? Non ho trovato il termine "cajazza" su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Immagino si tratti di un vocabolo regionale, probabilmente correlato al napoletano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In questo [*Dizionario del dialetto torrese con citazioni dalla letteratura napoletana*](https://www.academia.edu/11015218/Lettera_-_C_-_Dizionario_del_dialetto_torrese_con_citazioni_dalla_letteratura_napoletana) di Salvatore Argenziano e Gianna De Filippis si trova:

> **caiàzza**:  s. f. Gazza. Traslato: Donna linguacciuta. etim.  Lat. “gaja”.
>   *VEL.  *Non c’era n’ommo ch’avesse parlato, ca vernava ’n cajola la cajazza*

È un modo per indicare donne pettegole che passavano il tempo probabilmente parlando e sparlando.

Comment: Si tratta di un vocabolario di dialetto torrese, no?

Comment: @Charo con citazioni della letteratura napoletana

Comment: Sì, hai ragione, ma si tratta comunque di un dizionario di dialetto torrese. Vedi [qui](https://www.academia.edu/23191086/01_5-_A-B-C-_-STAMPA_-Dizionario_del_Dialetto_Torrese-_con_citazioni_dal_Dialetto_Napoletano-_da_Abbabbi%C3%A1_a_Cuzzut%C3%A8lla) la prefazione.